# ansible loop over file list and check file exists, if not download it

Tags: loops, ansible, yaml

Not sure how to have this logic implemented, I know how to do it a single file :

```
- name: Obtain information about a file
  win_stat:
    path: "C:\myfile.txt"
  register: fileinfo

- [...]
  when: fileinfo.exists == False
```

how should I go with a list of files?

Comment: that's all have txt extension and are under same directory?

Comment: I guess the question is how to bundle together the check + another action (here download) in one single loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to reduce the steps for doing this, you should be able to do your download step (not shown in your example) with `ignore_errors: yes` on your download commands. If you use a combination of `ignore_errors: yes` and `register`, you can even tell whether the command failed.

If you're looking to make it a bit more efficient, you can do the stat in a single task and then examine the results of that.  When you execute a task with a list, you get a hash of answers.

Assuming you have a list of file names/paths in `ssh_key_config`, you use the stat and then you can loop over the items (which conveniently have the file name in them).

```
- name: Check to see if file exists
  stat:
    path: "{{ remote_dir }}/{{ item }}"
  register: stat_results
  with_items: "{{ target_files }}"
  ignore_errors: True

- name: perform operation
  fetch:
    src: "{{ remote_dir }}/{{ item.item }}"
    dest: "{{ your_dest_dir }}"
    flat: yes
  with_items: "{{ stat_results.results }}"
  when: item.stat.exists == False
```

In this case, the assumptions are that `remote_dir` contains the remote directory on the host, `target_files` contains the actual file names, and `your_dest_dir` contains the location you want the files placed locally.

I don't do much with Windows and Ansible, but `win_stat` is documented pretty much the same as `stat`, so you can likely just replace that.

Also note that this expects the list of files, not a glob.  If you use a glob (for example, you want to retrieve all files with a certain extension from the remote), then you would not use the `with_items` clause, and you'd need to use the `item.stat.filename`  and/or `item.stat.path` to retrieve the file remotely (since the `item.item` would contain the request item, which would be the glob.

Comment: nicely done, thanks. side note, these loops appear so slow during execution ;(